# Smallest perfect square divisible by all elements of an array (with large numbers)

Tags: math

Given an array A[] with n elements, the task is to find S mod (10^9+7), in which S is the smallest perfect square which is divisible by all the elements A[i] (1<=i<=n) of the given array.

So, the problem is very easy if the value of A[i] and n is small. But in this case, I don't know what to do when A[i] can up to 10^7 and n can up to 10^5. So everybody help me pls!

Comment: I'd start by looking at the prime factorization of the LCF of the elements of A.  Then multiply the LCF by any of its prime factors which do not have an even power.  This should be your value S.  The rest is just plugging into the equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest integer X which is a multiple of all the A_i is called [the least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the A_i. It's also true that *every* common multiple of the A_i is divisible by X. So S is divisible by X, or equivalently S is a multiple of X.

The LCM can computed fairly efficiently by the algorithms mentioned in the wikipedia article, but remember our final goal is S, a perfect square, not X. Also, the size of X (and S) is likely to be enormous given the constraints in your problem.

Thus I think the correct approach is to use a modified [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (or just obtain from some online source a list of primes up to 3163) to completely factor all the A_i simultaneously into their prime power factorizations. Since the A_i < 10<sup>7</sup> you need only include primes <= 10<sup>3.5</sup>. Now, with each A_i factored into its prime power factorization use the [prime factorization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Using_prime_factorization) to find the LCM, but still retain this in prime power format, in other words don't yet multiply everything together. Next, scan through each of the powers and add 1 to any odd powers. Now you have the prime power factorization of S. Iterate through these prime powers, multiplying each one into the product and taking the product mod (10<sup>9</sup>+7) at each step.